# Coded UI Tests down casting not working

Tags: c#, automation, coded-ui-tests

I have been trying to introduce generics to our automation code and so I am trying to cast WpfControl to generic type T where T is constrained to be of type WpfControl.

```
return control as T;
```

T will always be a child of WpfControl yet when I am casting control which is of type WpfControl to the generic type it returns null. I have also tried to cast control to the exact child type for example something like:

```
var childControl = control as WpfTabList;
```

This still returns `null`. Anyone experience any similar issues?

See this [WpfControl Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.wpfcontrols.wpfcontrol.aspx)

Comment: If everything is as you describe, then it should work. I suspect there is something you are missing. May I suggest you: a) Step through in a debugger and see what the type of "control" is at runtime and b) Post more complete code.

Comment: Also check that control is not null! That's caught me out before.

Comment: where the line that invokes the constructor - can you add it please. (control = new....) you will probably solve it on your own when you get to find that line ;) (but if not - I'm still here)

Comment: you should also display or log `control.GetType().ToString()` to make sure that it's the type you expect...

Answer (score 0):

some recomendations:

First, In you generic method please use the geteric type specification. like

```
public T GetControl<T>(...) where T : WpfControl
```

there is a misconsistnace in your assumption and implemtation
 you are trying to match a `WpfControl` to a `WpfTabList` which is wrong in cases when a child control is not a TabList.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely works.  I have a whole set of these on my [github](https://github.com/spelltwister/CodedUIFluentExtensions/tree/master/CodedUIExtensions/CaptainPav.Testing.UI.CodedUI).

**Can you add more code that shows what control is set to?**

Here are some excerpts to show what this may look like.

```
public static T Find<T>(this UITestControl parent) where T : UITestControl, new()
    {
        return new T() { Container = parent };
    }

public static IEnumerable<T> FindAll<T>(this UITestControl parent) where T : UITestControl, new()
    {
        return parent.Find<T>().FindAllAsType();
    }

private static IEnumerable<T> FindAllAsType<T>(this T current) where T : UITestControl, new()
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(HtmlControl)))
        {
            return current.FindMatchingControls().Select(x => new T().ExtendFrom(x));
        }
        return current.FindMatchingControls().OfType<T>();
    }

private static IEnumerable<U> FindAllCastTo<T, U>(this T current) where T : UITestControl
    {
        return current.FindMatchingControls().Cast<U>();
    }
```

The most likely case is that the control type is not what you are trying to cast it to or that it is null.